# Classification Results Display

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-visualization

I am a bit new to python. I am working on classification of some data using Jupyter Notebook. I want my code to display the classification results, and also display the exact data that has been classified on the dataset. I have implemented 5 Machine Learning algorithms and here is the code for Decision Trees:
The dataset I am using has 11 features and 47 instances. I am using only the 2 features in X,

```
# Load data from input file
X = df.iloc[:, 5:7] 
y = df.iloc[:,10]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 
0, test_size = 0.3)

X_train:
array([[-0.05664779, -0.58110416],
   [ 0.42484065,  3.5857702 ],
   [-1.05270555, -0.53063454],
   [ 0.64734571,  0.67333113],
   [ 0.51518197, -0.22663851],
   [ 0.34780217, -0.29330293],
   [-1.08267179, -0.29346875],
   [ 1.22338025,  0.25858559],
   [-1.92566896,  0.60550589],
   [ 1.02700549, -0.88870573],
   [-2.19290617, -0.77885869],
   [ 0.14325145, -0.78980359],
   [ 1.86857648, -0.20176372],
   [ 0.89419424, -0.8407969 ],
   [ 0.8363162 ,  0.29999618],
   [-1.04567299,  1.65489006],
   [-1.25037945,  2.18641442],
   [ 0.69971696, -0.52016095],
   [-0.48005205, -0.49827114],
   [-0.10060947, -0.17589395],
   [ 0.02917319, -0.32619617],
   [ 1.20694636, -0.39488911],
   [-1.51508395, -0.79676853],
   [-0.22137603,  0.02061684],
   [-0.9658928 , -0.87727754],
   [-0.9286645 ,  1.24466936],
   [ 0.07129068,  0.10715181],
   [ 0.57682341,  1.13484127],
   [ 0.93138155, -0.63707242],
   [ 1.01005932, -0.76691879],
   [ 1.0114814 , -0.5027486 ],
   [-0.64643598, -0.85049806]])

  y_train:
```

45    0
26    1
15    0
25    1
16    0
40    0
20    1
41    1
8     1
13    0
5     0
17    0
34    0
14    0
37    0
7     1
38    1
1     0
12    0
35    1
24    1
6     1
23    1
36    1
21    0
19    1
9     1
39    1
46    0
3     0
0     0
44    0
Name: id, dtype: int64

```
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()

dtree.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = dtree.predict(X_test)
print(X_test)
```

This only displays the resulting `predictions` as follows:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

I understand that ML makes these prediction basing on y_train, which in this dataset has only the labels 1 or zero. My question is; how can i make the code to display not only y_train but also the corresponding features in that instance or the whole "row". eg. if its 1, and the row number/ etc.

I am really new to python. Please help

Comment: can you elaborate on your question. by giving example of what you want to display instead of `array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64)`

Comment: Please, add more information. Like what is in your X_train and y_train. And what are you trying to display?

Answer (score 0):

If viewing the prediction along with the features is the only problem, just use the below code.

```
myDf=pd.concat([X_train, predictions], axis=1, sort=False)
myDf
```

If not, elaborate the  question.